# How to make my user-define command solid in gdb

Tags: gdb

I defined a user-command in gdb, but I can't find it the next time.
How to make it still? I did't find the answer in [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html).

for example:

```
(gdb)define mycommand
>printf "--------backtrace----"
>where
>end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the command in your `~/.gdbinit` file, details of which can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbinit-man.html).  This configuration file is processed each time gdb is started, recreating your custom command.